# Joda DateTime disregard/remove milis in comparing for equality

Tags: java, jodatime

Is there an easier way to remove the millis part of joda DateTime?

Example: `2022-02-08T07:13:00.010Z` -> `2022-02-08T07:13:00.000Z`

I want to compare two datetimes.. but disregard the millis since the date/time I want to compare have zero millis.

One way I think is to format the date into string and parse it.. but since this will be run via schedule job every minute.. it will be better if there is an easier/lighter way to do this.

Is there an easier/lighter solution to disregard the millis when comparing 2 joda DateTime?

This is how I did it but I think there are better solutions (easier/lighter):

```
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    DateTime noMillis = new DateTime(
            now.getYear(),
            now.getMonthOfYear(),
            now.getDayOfMonth(),
            now.getHourOfDay(),
            now.getMinuteOfHour(),
            now.getSecondOfMinute());
```

Aside from this, I think it is also possible to use string formatter to convert DateTime to string and remove the millis.. then convert it back to DateTime (from String).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.withMillisOfSecond(0)` - to remove millis from `DateTime`.
Also, other options for comparing `DateTime` and ignoring millis are possible.

Here are some examples:

```java
DateTime t1 = DateTime.parse("2022-02-08T07:13:00.010Z");
DateTime t2 = DateTime.parse("2022-02-08T07:13:00.000Z");

// Option 1: set millis to 0
assertTrue(t1.withMillisOfSecond(0).equals(t2)); // Pass

// Option 2: remove millis from date
assertTrue(t1.minusMillis(t1.getMillisOfSecond()).equals(t2)); // Pass

// Option 3: compare that diff of millis less than 1000
// (If you want a check that t1 and t2 differentiate only in milliseconds)
assertTrue(t1.getMillis() - t2.getMillis() < 1000); // Pass
```

Comment: Option 1 will also pass for "2022-02-08T07:13:01.000Z" and "2022-02-08T07:13:00.999Z", which seems not what OP want.

Comment: Hi @samabcde. As I got, OP "want to compare two datetimes. but disregard the millis since the date/time I want to compare have zero millis". For that purposes `Option 1` is also an option.

Comment: @samabcde Thanks anyway, I've updated the answer to keep it more clear according to the comment

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it works! code is a lot cleaner